# Is it possible to override the home button using a service?

Tags: android, overriding

Basically, the back button is broken on my phone and I'd like to replace the home button to actually emulate the back button.

Is there a way to do this in a service so that regardless of what app I'm using, the home button is overridden to act like the back button?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the app you say. No, its not possible. Its the hardware connection issue. Programatically it can not be solved.
But for a particular app its possible. You can use [UP Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) instead. You may see the details of implementation in this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_navigation.htm).

Or you can override the Home button as

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the home button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                     
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to overriding devise button .

 in this code I override home button and menu button and back button

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){

            //some thing


        }else if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){

            //some thing                

        }else if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){


          }


        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Right, but this code only works for when you are in the actual app. I want it to override regardless of what app you are in.